# how can i input values of different data types in 2d list python?

Tags: python

I am very noob at Python. and also noob in English, Sorry.
I want to input mixed data type in one line in 2d list.

```
n = input("how many people? : ")
data = []

for i in range(n):
    data.append(list(map(str, input("Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :").split())))
```

if i enter code

```
2   
John 185 80
Tom 172 71
```

shows me

```
[['John', '185', '80'],['Tom', '172', '71']]
```

but i want input name in str, others in int, output like this.

```
[['John', 185, 80],['Tom', 172, 71]]
```

but if i change

```
data.append(list(map(str, input("Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :").split())))
```

this line of **str** to **int**, i can't input name because of error. ToT

Comment: `n` should be `int` right? and in the last code, did you mean you change it to `data.append(list(map(int, input("Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :").split())))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension from list `data` to convert its element to `int` if it contains numbers using `str.isdigit()` function. Also, note that `n` should be `int`:

```
n = int(input("how many people? : "))
data = []

for i in range(n):
    data.append(list(map(str, input("Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :").split())))

data = [[int(num) if num.isdigit() else num for num in item] for item in data]

print(data)

# how many people? : 2
# Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :John 185 80
# Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :Tom 172 71
# [['John', 185, 80], ['Tom', 172, 71]]
```

Or you can unpack the input value and cast the element containing numbers to `int`, then append the value to list:

```
n = input("how many people? : ")
data = []

for i in range(int(n)):
    name, height, weight = input("Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :").split()
    person = [name, int(height), int(weight)]
    data.append(person)

print(data)

# how many people? : 2
# Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :John 185 80
# Enter name, height(cm), weight(kg) :Tom 172 71
# [['John', 185, 80], ['Tom', 172, 71]]
```